# Can't flash esp32 using esp-prog on PlatformIO

Tags: esp32

I am using esp-prog JTAG programmer to flash my esp32-s3-wroom-1 module on PlatformIO. I'm using Serial communication to upload the code, not the JTAG one, I can see two active COMPORTS on device manager and Platformio, but when selecting COMPORT n+1  (Serial coms COMport), I get this error: `A fatal error occurred: Could not open COM20, the port doesn't exist` . Selecting other Comport returns with same error. This is very common bug, which i don't know how to solve, usually I use Zadig to change drivers back and forth till Windows changes COMPORT numbers and then Platformio recognises them. Maybe there is easier way to fix this bug? Or am I missing something?

[image]
[image]